# использование ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Подскажите как  правильно обернуть в scrollview свою разметку, дело в том что не все элементы влазят в экран, а точнее нижний край моей DiagramView скрыт экраном. Или может как то иначе можно решить данный вопрос. Вот моя разметка:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BalanceFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="32dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="32dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balance_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/balance_result_title"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_grey"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balance_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="@color/balance_color"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            tools:text="45000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/divider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="32dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/expense_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/balance_expenses_title"
                android:textColor="@color/medium_grey"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/expense_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textColor="@color/expense_color"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:text="45000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="32dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/income_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/balance_income_title"
                android:textColor="@color/medium_grey"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/income_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textColor="@color/income_color"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:text="45000" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/divider" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="32dp">

        <com.example.user.loftmoney.DiagramView
            android:id="@+id/diagram_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Что значит "скрыт экраном"?

Comment: Если просто не входит в экран, то надо уменьшить высоту других элементов, который в этом разметке занимают слишком много места, но содержат минимум информации. Еще и паддинг везде...

Comment: Да, просто не входит в экран, ну то есть не целесообразно делать скроллинг?

Comment: В этом случае нет. У вас три строчки текста занимают три четверти экрана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

//--> ваша верстка здесь

</ScrollView>
```